# How to make Sphinx only return exact matches for conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

What is the best way to make Sphinx not use full-text search on conditions?
So if I query for "Bannana", and set a condition that the "type" must be "fruit", exactly. So it wouldn't do a full-text search on the condition and return results with the type as "fruits".

Hope that makes sense,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the condition must be set as an attribute in sphinx. This will allow you to filter on the attribute and only return records of type "fruits".

Comment: be careful though cant filter on string attrributes, only numeric attributes. Can use something like CRC32 to make a number from a string tho.

Answer (score 0):

Can use
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-index-exact-words

to make sure not match stemmed versions. I've no idea how to set that via thinking-sphinx.

Then can do

```
bannana @type =fruit
```

as the text query.